# change the time output of the time variable in windows command line to use in batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Goal: Backup files from subdirectories with a specific extension to another directory using a batch file.

```
forfiles /P C:\Users\user\Desktop\testdest\ -D 3 /C "cmd /c IF @isdir == TRUE rd /S /Q @path" 
mkdir C:\Users\user\Desktop\testdest\%date%
FOR /R C:\Users\user\Desktop\testsrc\ %%A in (*.txt) do (
echo %%A
copy "%%A" "C:\Users\user\Desktop\testdest\%DATE%\%time:~0,2%_%time:~3,2%_%time:~6,2%_%time:~9,2%_%%~nxA
)
```

I tried multiple ways finding a way to make the file names unique. 
Unfortunately there are files in the subdirectories that have the same name as files in other subdirectories, so to make them unique in the target directory, they need a pre- or postfix that makes them unique.
Tried a counter variable, but could not figure out how to increment it.
I ended up trying to use the time variable, but it seems to stay the same in the whole batch file run.

Output is like this:

```
copy "C:\Users\user\Desktop\testsrc\sub\subsub\311.txt" "C:\Users\user\Desktop\testdest\01.02.2018\ 9_24_31_52_311.txt

copy "C:\Users\user\Desktop\testsrc\sub\subsub\312.txt" "C:\Users\user\Desktop\testdest\01.02.2018\ 9_24_31_52_312.txt
```

the time output stays the same, what is a problem, when there are multiple files with the same name.

So why is the time output not changing the millisecond?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with [delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html):

```
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
forfiles /P C:\Users\user\Desktop\testdest\ -D 3 /C "cmd /c IF @isdir == TRUE rd /S /Q @path" 
mkdir C:\Users\user\Desktop\testdest\%date%
FOR /R C:\Users\user\Desktop\testsrc\ %%A in (*.txt) do (
  echo %%A
  copy "%%A" "C:\Users\user\Desktop\testdest\%DATE%\!time:~0,2!_!time:~3,2!_!time:~6,2!_!time:~9,2!_%%~nxA
)
```

Mind that the %time% could differ on different machines as it relies on local settings.

Answer (score 1):

thank you so much @Magoo and @npocmaka

it worked like a charme.

what confused me is that in the batch output, the !time! variables are not shown as expanded.

for example the output of

```
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
Set timeexpand=!time:~0,2!_!time:~3,2!_!time:~6,2!_!time:~9,2!
copy "%%A" "C:\Users\user\Desktop\testdest\%DATE%\!timeexpand!_%%~nxA
```

is

```
copy "C:\Users\user\Desktop\testsrc\sub\subsub\331.txt" "C:\Users\user\Desktop\testdest\01.02.2018\!timeexpand!_331.txt
```

while the variables are not shown "as expanded" in the copy command "echo", the file names the script produces have the right timestamp.

for exmaple

```
10_18_28_59_1.txt
10_18_28_60_2.txt
10_18_28_61_3.txt
```

My final script looks like this:

```
eventcreate /L APPLICATION /SO backup /T INFORMATION /ID 337 /D "Starting copy of database files"
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
forfiles /P D:\backup\bckup\ -D 3 /C "cmd /c IF @isdir == TRUE rd /S /Q @path" 
mkdir D:\backup\bckup\%date%
FOR /R D:\dbs %%F in (*.mdf) do ( 
timeout 1
Set timeexpandmdf=!time:~0,2!_!time:~3,2!_!time:~6,2!_!time:~9,2!
copy "%%F" "D:\backup\bckup\%date%\%%~nF_!timeexpandmdf!_%%~xF" 
)
FOR /R D:\dbs %%F in (*.ldf) do (
timeout 1
Set timeexpandldf=!time:~0,2!_!time:~3,2!_!time:~6,2!_!time:~9,2!
copy "%%F" "D:\backup\bckup\%date%\%%~nF_!timeexpandldf!_%%~xF" 
)
echo %DATE% %time% >> d:\backup\file.age
ENDLOCAL
eventcreate /L APPLICATION /SO backup /T INFORMATION /ID 337 /D "copy of database files done"
```

Comment: Does your `DATE` variable use forward slashes? 02/01/2018

Comment: Fortunately I'm on a system where %date% expands to 01.01.1971

Answer (score 1):

This seems clearer to me in PowerShell. When you are confident that the correct files will be copied with the correct names, remove the `-WhatIf` from the `Copy-Item` cmdlet.

Doing it in PowerShell relieves you of having to consider what the local date and time format requires.

```
$testsrc = 'C:\src\t\ct1'
$testdest = 'C:\src\t\ct2'
$thedate = Get-Date -Format 'yyyyMMdd'

Remove-Item -Path $testdest\* -Recurse
New-Item -Path $testdest -Name $thedate -ItemType 'directory' | Out-Null
Get-ChildItem -Path $testsrc -Recurse -Filter *.txt |
    ForEach-Object { Copy-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination "$testdest\$thedate\$(Get-Date -Format 'HH_mm_ss_ffff_')$($_.Name)" -WhatIf }
```

One thing I notice about this is that the millisecond value does not always change often enough for every file to have a different timestamp. That could be a problem if you have files of the same name in two different directories of the source.

Comment: thanks for the hint, that the millisecond could not change often enough. added a timeout 1 to my script

Answer (score 0):

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

FOR /R C:\Users\user\Desktop\testsrc\ %%A in (*.txt) do (
echo %%A
copy "%%A" "C:\Users\user\Desktop\testdest\!DATE!\!time:~0,2!_!time:~3,2!_!time:~6,2!_!time:~9,2!_%%~nxA
)

ENDLOCAL
```

Please use the `search` facility to read many articles on `delayed expansion` to find out why.

Comment: I am not sure this will work well. The `DATE` variable might easily contain forward slashes. In addition, parsing the `TIME` variable will fail if the user's configuration is not set for this format.

Comment: @lit: Of course, in the general case you're quite correct. OP is sufficiently astute to have performed the appropriate time-manipulation, so if data produced a similar problem, then no doubt that could be dealt with similarly. But true, those with other date- and time-formats (especially the evil am/pm) would need to adjust their date/time-processing to suit. And the real problem is the date-format as any format other than (yy)yy-mm-dd will not sort nicely.

Comment: Will using the `DATE` variable work if it contains forward slashes (the default en-US configuration)? `02/01/2018`

Comment: @lit: no. The `/` will be interpreted as backslashes so there will be extra and most probably non-existent subdirectories in the path. If you echo **F** into `xcopy` rather than using `copy` though, the directories and files will be created....The conversion can be flaky, especially in commands which accept switches.